# Ambiguous error message when trying to insert NULL value for UNIQUE attribute in a table

Tags: sqlite, unique-constraint

```
 CREATE TABLE access_type(
 id NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 access_type VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
 access_value VARCHAR(2) UNIQUE
 );
```

### Case I:

When I tried to insert NULL for access_value attribute, i got below output:

```
sqlite> insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (3,'execute',NULL);
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: access_type.access_type
```

### Case II:

When I tried to insert NULL for access_type attribute, i got below output:

```
sqlite> insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (3,NULL,'E');
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: access_type.access_value
```

I want to know why sqlite3 is giving error for **access_type** when I am inserting NULL for **access_value** in the first case and giving error for **access_value** when inserting NULL for **access_type**. Please help

Comment: Multiple nulls should be allowed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22699498/1261752.  Are you certain that there are no other indexes or constraints on the table?

Comment: @C Perkins: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I checked multiple null values are allowed. Also, there are not other indexes or constraints on the table. @Mike T response is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1** didn't fail because of the NULL (NULL is considred different to all other NULLs) it failed because there was already a row that has **execute** in the **access_type** column.

i.e. the messages tells you that the UNIQUE contrainst that failed (was in conflict) was the **access_type** column.

**Case 2** likewise failed due to another row having 3 in the **id** column.

Perhaps consider the following (note the DROP TABLE so that it is rerunnable) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS access_type;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS access_type(
 id NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 access_type VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
 access_value VARCHAR(2) UNIQUE
 );
 insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (3,'execute',NULL);
 insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (4,NULL,'E');
 insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (5,NULL,NULL);
```

When run the messages are :-

```
insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (3,'execute',NULL)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.091s


-- insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (3,NULL,'E'); /* fails because id  3 has been used */
 insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (4,NULL,'E')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.095s


insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (5,NULL,NULL)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.107s
```

You probably want to review the use of UNIQUE as you are imposing quite a strict set of terms. At a guess you would want a number of rows to have execute as the access_type and you probably want the same access_value. What you possibly do not want is the same id and access_type and/or the same access_value.

So you might want ID 3 with an access type of exceute and ID 3 also having a row for a noop type. You then probably want a compound PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index.

As an example conisder the following adaptation :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS access_type;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS access_type(
 id NUMBER NOT NULL /* PRIMARY KEY */ /* PRIMARY KEY IMPLIES UNIQUE */,
 access_type VARCHAR(10) /* UNIQUE */,
 access_value VARCHAR(2) /* UNIQUE */ , /*<<<<< added comma */
 PRIMARY KEY (id,access_type) /*<<<<< compound PRIMARY KEY */
 );
 insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (3,'execute',NULL);
 insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (3,'noop',NULL);
 insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (4,NULL,'E');
 insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (5,NULL,NULL);
```

However, if  `insert into access_type (id,access_type,access_value) values (3,'execute',NULL);` were tried then it would fail.

You might also want to consider INSERT OR IGNORE in which case the UNIQUE constraint conflict would be a NOOP rather than a failure.